# Calling generic method

Tags: java

I am getting following error when I execute the code mentioned below:

```
TestGenerics1.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
                              arr.get(i).eat();
                                        ^
symbol:   method eat()
location: class Object
1 error
```

The issue I am facing is reproduced with the help of following sample code:

```
import java.util.*;

abstract class Animal
{
    void eat() { System.out.println("animal eating"); }
}

class Dog extends Animal
{
    void bark() { }
}

class Cat extends Animal
{
    void meow() { }
}

class RedCat extends Cat { }

public class TestGenerics1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new TestGenerics1().go();
    }

    public void go()
    {
        List<Cat> arrAnimals = new ArrayList<Cat>(Arrays.asList(new RedCat(), new Cat()));

        takeAnimals(arrAnimals);
    }

    //public static void takeAnimals(List<Cat> arr)
    public static void takeAnimals(List<? super RedCat> arr)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++)
        {
            arr.get(i).eat();
        }
    }
}
```

If I uncomment `public static void takeAnimals(List<Cat> arr)` and comment out `public static void takeAnimals(List<? super RedCat> arr)` then it works good.

Why does it not work with `public static void takeAnimals(List<? super RedCat> arr)` ?

Comment: `? super RedCat` allows e.g. `List<Object>` to be passed in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: Mehotd should be 'takeAnimals(List<? extends Animal> arr)' to solve compile error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List<? super RedCat>` is list of some types which are supertype of `RedCat`.

The compiler cannot figure out which type is passed and does not guaranteed `eat()` method exists.

Instead, you should use `extends`:

```
List<? extends Cat>
```

Comment: I think it should be `List<? extends Animal>` since `Animal` defines method `eat()`.

Comment: Good point. But I think wildcard is good in situation where we want to restrict/narrow down type of input list

Comment: `List<? extends Cat>` allows `Cat` and suptypes of `Cat` only. In your program, they're  `Cat` and `RedCat`